# pwm and pull up/down

Tags: pwm

I am an electrical engineer and feel I should know this, but I for the life of me still cant quite get this concept.

I understand conceptually the idea behind a pull up or a pull down, in that we want the IC to read a high state, by default, in the case of a pull up and low by default in case of pull down. But earlier to day an engineer was saying that we needed a lower pull down resistor to drive a pwm from 3 to 5 volts. I still dont get/understand the connection between a pull up/pull down and pwm signal? I get that its ideal to drive a motor using a pwm signal and a resistor could be used as an impedance to drive the pwm, but i still dont get the use of resistor in pwm to pull it "up" or "down"? an example, links or clarifications would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: While I'm absolutely positive that a more capable person will happen along and simply answer this, I feel that I need to ask for a schematic of the situation you are describing. I'm not sure I understand the relationship of all the components in play.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, probably caused by the lack of context. You'll have to supply more details about the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at a combination of several concepts, and that's the source of some of the confusion.  PWM doesn't really have anything to do with the situation.  It just happens to be a form of a digital signal that goes from the output of one thing (driving circuit), to the input of another (the motor).

The input (the motor's electronics) is really just trying to sense whether the signal is high or low.  It's measuring the signal voltage.  You may find (or place) a pull up resistor there, but it really acts as part of the output circuitry that's trying to drive it.  You may find it easier to pretend that any pull up resistor is attached to the output instead.

The output (or driver) is where we need to look.  Generally, to drive a signal high and low requires two switches.  One switch connects the output to the supply (or drive) voltage, and the other connects it to ground.  This is a "push-pull" circuit.   Many times, the output stage will omit one of the switches, most often it will be the one to the supply voltage.  In that case, the pull up resistor takes the place of the missing switch.  It's not nearly as good a solution, but it allows us to solve other problems.  What happens in this case is that with the "lower" switch open, the resistor is responsible for sourcing the current that pulls the output up.  That's limited by the resistor and the amount of current drawn by the input stage.  When the lower switch closes, the output is grounded but also there's (wasted) current through the resistor.  This extra current also affects the ability of the switch to bring the voltage to ground.

In real life, the output may swing between other voltages than Vdd and ground; that's a design choice.  And sometimes it's the lower switch that's omitted; in which case, we'd use a pull down resistor.

There are other cases where a resistor is applied to a signal to attempt to "pull" the voltage up or down.  In these cases, the current through the added resistor is really just "fighting" against the other currents in the circuit.  These are usually attempted "fixes" rather than a design technique that you'd find in the literature.

Answer (score -5):

That engineer is mentioning that lower pull down register means with less resistance so when the circuit gets completed as on when the motor is switched on the pwm should divide more volts in motor 5 v than 3v. Its voltage divider concept he is talking about.

By lowering down pull down register the fall of voltage across resister will decrease and the more volts from 3 v to 5 v in this case would be available for motor.

Comment: This answer is as confusing as the question.